# model.fit throws me error "Expected tensor of type int64 but got type float" at random epoch

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to fit this model with tensorflow :

```py
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, load_model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, Dropout, BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
import tensorflow.keras.regularizers as regularizers
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint

regularizer = regularizers.l2(REGULARIZATION_RATE)

model = Sequential(
    [
        Input(shape=[input_shape]),
        
        Dense(64, activation="relu", kernel_regularizer=regularizer),
        Dense(64, activation="relu", kernel_regularizer=regularizer),
        Dense(32, activation="relu", kernel_regularizer=regularizer),

        Dense(units=output_shape, activation="softmax"),
    ]
)

optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=LEARNING_RATE)

checkpointer_callback = ModelCheckpoint(
    filepath=f"models/{model_name}/{model_name}.hdf5",
    monitor="val_loss",
    verbose=False,
    save_best_only=True,
)

model.summary()

model.compile(
    optimizer=optimizer, loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"]
)
```

But when I train my model like so :

```py
history = model.fit(
    x_train,
    y_train,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    epochs=NUM_EPOCHS,
    validation_split=VALIDATION_SPLIT,
    verbose=VERBOSE,
    callbacks=[
        checkpointer_callback,
        csv_logger_callback,
        early_stopping_callback,
        tensorboard_callback,
    ],
)
```

I get the following error at a random epoch at the line of my `model.fit`:

`Expected tensor of type int64 but got type float [[{{node Equal}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_1276164]`

Full error :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[47], line 9
      5 print(f"Training model {model_name}...\n")
      6 start_time = time.time()
----> 9 history = model.fit(
     10     x_train,
     11     y_train,
     12     batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
     13     epochs=NUM_EPOCHS,
     14     validation_split=VALIDATION_SPLIT,
     15     verbose=VERBOSE,
     16     callbacks=[
     17         checkpointer_callback,
     18         csv_logger_callback,
     19         early_stopping_callback,
     20         tensorboard_callback,
     21     ],
     22 )
     25 training_duration = get_timestamp(time.time() - start_time)
     27 print("\n-------------\n")
File ~/miniconda3/envs/kinected/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

File ~/miniconda3/envs/kinected/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py:53, in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     51 try:
     52   ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 53   tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     54                                       inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     55 except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     56   if name is not None:

InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node Equal defined at (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main

  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code

  File "/Users/louislecouturier/miniconda3/envs/kinected/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 17, in <module>

  File "/Users/louislecouturier/miniconda3/envs/kinected/lib/python3.11/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 1077, in launch_instance

  File "/Users/louislecouturier/miniconda3/envs/kinected/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 739, in start

  File "/Users/louislecouturier/miniconda3/envs/kinected/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 195, in start

  File "/Users/louislecouturier/miniconda3/envs/kinected/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py", line 607, in run_forever

  File "/Users/louislecouturier/miniconda3/envs/kinected/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1922, in _run_once

  File "/Users/louislecouturier/miniconda3/envs/kinected/lib/python3.11/asyncio/events.py", line 80, in _run

  File "/Users/louislecouturier/miniconda3/envs/kinected/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 529, in dispatch_queue

  File "/Users/louislecouturier/miniconda3/envs/kinected/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 518, in process_one

  File "/Users/louislecouturier/miniconda3/envs/kinected/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 424, in dispatch_shell

  File "/Users/louislecouturier/miniconda3/envs/kinected/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 766, in execute_request

  File "/Users/louislecouturier/miniconda3/envs/kinected/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 429, in do_execute

  File "/Users/louislecouturier/miniconda3/envs/kinected/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 549, in run_cell

  File "/Users/louislecouturier/miniconda3/envs/kinected/lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3048, in run_cell

  File "/Users/louislecouturier/miniconda3/envs/kinected/lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3103, in _run_cell

  File "/Users/louislecouturier/miniconda3/envs/kinected/lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/core/async_helpers.py", line 129, in _pseudo_sync_runner

  File "/Users/louislecouturier/miniconda3/envs/kinected/lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3308, in run_cell_async

  File "/Users/louislecouturier/miniconda3/envs/kinected/lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3490, in run_ast_nodes

  File "/Users/louislecouturier/miniconda3/envs/kinected/lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3550, in run_code

  File "/var/folders/85/04dxvd3x7wsbz88m2jf0z4000000gn/T/ipykernel_6585/1245095393.py", line 9, in <module>

  File "/Users/louislecouturier/miniconda3/envs/kinected/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler

  File "/Users/louislecouturier/miniconda3/envs/kinected/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1807, in fit

  File "/Users/louislecouturier/miniconda3/envs/kinected/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1401, in train_function

  File "/Users/louislecouturier/miniconda3/envs/kinected/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1384, in step_function

  File "/Users/louislecouturier/miniconda3/envs/kinected/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1373, in run_step

  File "/Users/louislecouturier/miniconda3/envs/kinected/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1155, in train_step

  File "/Users/louislecouturier/miniconda3/envs/kinected/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1249, in compute_metrics

  File "/Users/louislecouturier/miniconda3/envs/kinected/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/compile_utils.py", line 620, in update_state

  File "/Users/louislecouturier/miniconda3/envs/kinected/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/utils/metrics_utils.py", line 77, in decorated

  File "/Users/louislecouturier/miniconda3/envs/kinected/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/metrics/base_metric.py", line 140, in update_state_fn

  File "/Users/louislecouturier/miniconda3/envs/kinected/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/metrics/base_metric.py", line 723, in update_state

  File "/Users/louislecouturier/miniconda3/envs/kinected/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/metrics/accuracy_metrics.py", line 426, in categorical_accuracy

  File "/Users/louislecouturier/miniconda3/envs/kinected/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/utils/metrics_utils.py", line 969, in sparse_categorical_matches

Expected tensor of type int64 but got type float
     [[{{node Equal}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_1276164]
```

I am using a M1 MacBook Pro

Python     `v3.11`
Tensorflow `v2.15.0`

I don't know how to understand this error... My inputs are all in `float32`, my labels are one-hot encoded...

What am I doing wrong ? What is is expecting an `int64`?

Comment: First think you should check is if your labels are all using the same datatype.

Comment: @Lescurel Thanks for your answer, I've tried to do this `labels = labels.astype("float32")` but I still get the error

Comment: You'll have to create a [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if you want more help. As it stands, the only thing we can give you is hints on what to look for. Doing so will probably help you find the issue yourself too.

Comment: I actually recreated it couple of times haha... The weird thing is that the issue occurs at a random epoch so my model and data should be "fine"... After some more research, it is an `InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error` but I still have no clues of the cause...

Comment: Looks like changing the batch size from 8 to 128 "solved" the issue...